# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /register_trainee/succesfull User has no profile

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I was Trying to Extend User Model Using a One-To-One Link

when I was trying to create a User Object This Error Popped Up

here is my models.Py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    phonenumber = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and here is my views.py:

```
def trainee_succesfull(request):
    new_trainee = User()
    d = request.POST
    new_trainee.first_name = d['firstname']
    new_trainee.last_name = d['lastname']
    new_trainee.profile.phonenumber = d['phonenumber']
    new_trainee.password = d['password']


    new_trainee.save()

    return render(request, 'trainee/message.html')
```

I know that this question has been answered before but I could not fix the error by looking at the solutions.

I would really appreciate it if someone Can Help.

Answer (score 0):

`user.profile` object is not created automatically.

You need to add this to your code.

```
profile = Profile(user = new_trainee)
```